# Strange Behaviour With jQuery.find()

Tags: jquery-selectors

I can't quite understand why the find behaves here:

```
var data = $("<html><title>hello</title><body><form><ul><li>here</li></ul></form></body><ul><li></li></ul></html>");
alert(data.find("form").length);
alert(data.find("ul").length);
```

1. It doesn't find the form
2. It doesn't find the second UL

I've also put up a jsfiddle for this-

http://jsfiddle.net/erick382/YP9kz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't find the `form` element because it's effectively the root element of the collection (it's a direct child of the `body` element). If you change it to `.filter`, it will find the `form`:

```
alert(data.filter("form").length); // 1
```

It doesn't find the second `ul` element because it's outside of the `body` element, which is invalid (jQuery puts the second `ul` in the root of the collection - use `filter` and you'll be able to find that one too).

jQuery removes the `html` element and the `body` element from the collection. If you log the contents of the collection it makes it a bit clearer what's going on:

> [`<title>​hello​</title>​`, `<form>​…​</form>​`, `<ul>​…​</ul>​`]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `each` to the `ul` search. I added James's answer to the demo as well.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YP9kz/2/)